# OpenGL : error with invalid format but NULL data

Tags: c, opengl

Sometimes we need to initialize a texture without data. So I want to write an utility function, something like that:

```
GLuint create_texture(GLenum internal_format, int width, int height)
{
    GLuint id;
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    return id;
}
```

I want to be able to initialize with any format I want (`GL_RGB`, `GL_RGBA`, etc...).
However, this will crash if the `format` argument doesn't match the `internal_format` argument even if *there is no actual data*. Is it possible to avoid this error without using an external table that will match the `format` for the given `internal_format` (which is possible by the help of the [this page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml), at *Errors* paragraph)? However, this is a bit tedious, so I was wondering if there is an alternative.

We can't use `format=internal_format` because some values are not compatible, like `GL_RGBA16F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to OpenGL 4.2, the [`glTexStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml) method does exactly what you need. It allocates the storage for a texture but does not initialize it with any data.